# How to make Vim remember a defined variable in Python?

Tags: python, vim

I want Vim to remember a defined Python variable when I run it again. 
Is there a way?

Example:

```
[n] : line n on vim.

[1] a = 2

[2] b = a + 1

[3] print(b)
```

If I write:

```
:1,2w !python
```

and then:

```
:3w !python
```

I'd like to get the answer:

```
3
```

Instead, I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "< stdin >", line 1, in < module >
NameError: name 'b' is not defined

shell returned 1
```

Comment: What is the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: thanks, I will study more about getting help on stackoverflow.

Comment: Strictly speaking, Vim does remember the variable - all the source code is still loaded in the buffer; you just ask Vim to pass only parts of the buffer to Python. You rather want the Python interpreter to remember program state, something which is at odds with the `:!` command, which launches a _fresh_ instance of the executable each time.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `!python` you run an external Python binary. Every time you run `!python` you run a new non-initialized Python that doesn't remember anything from your previous session.

To remember your calculations you need to use the internal, built-in Python. Use [`:python`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html) or [`:python3`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html).

Also see "[Execute Python from within current file](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Execute_Python_from_within_current_file)".